# Limit approaching function equals 0, then limit approaching reciprocal of function is infinity

Tags: limits

I'm having difficulty proving whether the following statement is true or not:

For any function $f(x)$, if $$\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = 0$$, then $$\lim_{x\to c} {1\over f(x)} = ∞$$

I have tried making x a real number and tested different functions. I found that it is possible to solve, but I'm not too sure how to approach the "proving" part of the question.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Edit: I know this may sound rudimentary and rather stupid, but, is it sufficient as 'proof' to state something like:
since $$\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = 0$$, then $$\lim_{x\to c}{1\over f(x)} = {1\over 0}=∞$$ because $$lim_{x\to c}{1\over 0} $$ will always be infinity?

Comment: Consider the function $f(x)=x$ and $c=0$ then $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{f(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}=DNE$

Comment: No. You can't do that. Remember the law on the limit of quotients? By the way, when you write $\infty$, do you mean it as $+\infty$?

Comment: How can I help if you dont answer my question?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - and yes, I do mean it as +∞. I apologise for not understanding as it has been a few years since I last properly did maths and am only just revisiting everything.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\lim\limits_{x\to h}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\dfrac{\lim\limits_{x\to h} f(x)}{\lim\limits_{x\to h} g(x)}$

Also note that $\lim\limits_{x\to h} k=k$ for any constant $k$. Hope it helps.

Comment: This is a bit sloppy, since $\frac{1}{0}$ isn't a real number so "limit of quotient is quotient of limits" doesn't strictly apply.

Comment: Though I suppose it depends on what your statement of "limit of quotient is quotient of limits" is.